# PHP passing values from generated textboxes

Tags: php, textbox, html-table

I'm creating a PHP web application in combination with SQL to order stuff. I'm randomly generating textboxes based on the amount of records I have. I want to pass the individual values to insert to the database. I want each cell to have a textbox in which I can input values and pass them with that cell. So if I want to order 2 of cell one I want to pass that value into a database.

Here's the code:

```
$i = 0;
        if ($AanbodsTabel === false){
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($AanbodsTabel)){
            echo "<tr><td width = 4%>". htmlentities($row['Fustcode']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td width = 8%>" . htmlentities($row['cultivar']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td width = 6%>" . htmlentities($row['AantalFust']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td width = 6%>" . htmlentities($row['AantalPerFust']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td width = 6%>" . htmlentities($row['AantalStelen']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td width = 4%><input type ='text' id='Bestelbox' value='' name='AantalBestellen".$i."'></td>";
            echo "<td width = 6%>" . htmlentities($row['AantalFustBesteld']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td width = 6%>" . htmlentities($row['AantalStelenBesteld']) . "</td>";
    135:    echo '<td width = 8%><a href="Home.php?aanbodid='. htmlentities($row['aanbodid']) .'&hoeveelheid='. $_GET["AantalBestellen$i"]. '"'
                    . ' class = "btnBestel">Bestel</a></td></tr>';
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
```

The error I'm getting is undefined index. I guess this is because the name isn't unique. But whatever I do I still get the error.

I'm getting:

> undefined index: AantalBestellen0 on line 135;

Comment: To help you find an answer we need to have more information. Please give us more details about the error and the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use javascript for example
note i will bold the code you need, the rest is context.
**note** this is from a similar project of mine but you should get the point.

```
<div id="meldingen_top_div">
           <?php 

        echo "<div class='alert_Top_Div_Left_Outer'>
             <input type='submit' value='Openstaande Meldingen' class='btnLoad' name='' onclick='toggleThis(" . '"' . "#meldTableTop" . '"' . "), toggleThis(".'"'.".alert_Top_Div_Left_Inner".'"'.")'/>

       <div class='alert_Top_Div_Left_Inner'>
       <table class='tableRed' id='meldTableTop'><caption/><thead/><tfoot/><tbody>";

        $sqlVII = "SELECT Meldingen.Melding_id, FORMAT(Meldingen.Melding_datum, 'dd-mM-yyyy') AS Melding_datum, Producten.Product_naam, Leveranciers.Leverancier_naam, Meldingen.Melding_notitie 
FROM MovieWorld.dbo.Producten,
 MovieWorld.dbo.Meldingen,
 MovieWorld.dbo.Categorieen,
  MovieWorld.dbo.Leveranciers
 WHERE Producten.Product_id = Meldingen.Product_id AND Producten.Categorie_id = Categorieen.Categorie_id AND Categorieen.Leverancier_id = Leveranciers.Leverancier_id AND Producten.Product_actief = 1 AND Meldingen.Melding_actief = 1
";

        $resV= $db->executeQuery($sqlVII);
                    $i=1;

                    if($resV!=FALSE){
                    while($arrx = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resV)){
```

### Code wich is relevant for you:

```
    echo "<tr>

    <td><p class='meldDate'>{$arrx['Melding_datum']}</p></td>
    <td>{$arrx['Product_naam']}</td>
    <td>{$arrx['Leverancier_naam']}</td>   
    <td><input id='txt{$i} type='text' name='thisdoesntevenmatter' value='..'/></td>
    <td><img src='somerandompath.png' onclick='getTxt(".'"txt{$i}"'.")'/></td>
 </tr>"



    $i=$i+1;
                    }



                    }else{}echo '</tbody></table></div></div>';
           ?>
        </div>
```

and the Javascript function

```
function getTxt(id){
    var tempId = document.getElementById(id).value;
return tempId;
}
```

however.. you can also send the value back into a php variable, OR use AJAX to pass it to an PHP class to insert it into the Database.

**edit**

Your quotes in line 135: seem incorrect. try this:

```
    echo '<td width = 8%><a href="Home.php?aanbodid={htmlentities($row['aanbodid']) }&hoeveelheid={$_GET['AantalBestellen$i']}"'
                    . ' class = "btnBestel">Bestel</a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: i think it is easier if i could send you the code :p

Comment: Think that would be easier too:P

Comment: BTW, your quotes in line 135: are not correct. now it is this                    <td><input type="text" value="meh" id="txt2"/></td>

Comment: i edited my answer, see the last section, let me know if that is the problem. it looks like the double quotes of your ahref arent closing correctly but i could be wrong, it can never hurt to try (delete my previous answer, it was for jsfiddle)

Comment: I keep the value empty because it has to be unset in the beginning.

Comment: correct me if im wrong but is this even valid? $_GET["AantalBestellen$i"]

Comment: your hoeveelheid is your textbox and you are calling the name of the textbox instead of the value, at least it looks like that.

Answer (score 0):

Where you get undefined index? on that `$_POST['AantalBestellen']` ?

Use

```
if (isset($_POST['AantalBestellen'])) { }
```

to identify that the post value has been set

same do later for the hoeveelheid:

```
if (isset($_GET['hoeveelheid'])) { }
```

echo-ing the input field:

```
echo "<td width = 4%><input type ='text' id='Bestelbox' value='" . $_GET['hoeveelheid'] . "' name='AantalBestellen'></td>";
```

Also, dont forget to clear the spaces in:

```
'&hoeveelheid = '. $_POST //near the =
```